# How to Integrate Magento API in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce1-app

I want to use the magento api to perform operations like add, edit, delete etc.. from salesforce.

I want to sync my salesforce data into magento, but I am not getting any good documentation related to this.

Can any one please guide me the steps. So that I can Integrate Magento API into Salesforce.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the [Magneto SOAP API](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html) and the corresponding WSDL path for your Magneto host. You will most likely want something like:

```
http://magentohost/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1
```

Run this through [Wsdl2Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts#WSDL2Apex), and you will get Apex classes that you can use to callout to the available [API methods](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html#Introduction-APIMethods).

Alternatively, there appears to be a [REST API](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html) if that is your preference.

Comment: I did the same process but when generating from wsdl I used the magento wsdl. it gives an error like  *Error: Failed to parse wsdl: Found schema import from location http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/. External schema import not supported*

Comment: I make an alternative version of Wsdl2Apex via work. See the [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer). This has better support for importing elements. Can you share the WSDL URL?

Comment: I don't have any live magento version which url I can provide. For checking the magento wsdl below url can be used http://magento.webkul.com/Marketplace/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl

Comment: Still I did not get any solution. Can you please help me out in getting the solution for this integration. That will be really very helpful to me. Thanks

Comment: The WSDL in question uses the `rpc` style on the SOAP binding. This isn't directly supported by WebServiceCallout.invoke. Instead you will need to use the REST API.